# Go from local to public with Craft 3

Tags: craft3

Is there a lesson/tutorial/docs about going from local to production on server with Craft 3?

- What files should be uploaded  ( and which not )
- What folders need to be one level up of the root - where to change the paths to this folders
- Change config files.
- Go from dev to production.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the discussion in this SE question: [Best way to deploy Craft3 to webserver?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28519/best-way-to-deploy-craft3-to-webserver)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew, i will check it out. I love your work with Seomatic plugin by the way, i use it a lot, and for shure i will use it on Craft 3 too.

Comment: Awesome! Hope the discussion in that thread helps.

Comment: I install everything manually, i don´t use the console. It´s the way i use to do things in Craft 2, i hope this is not a problem.

Comment: Hi Andrew, i check your resource, and see your article Setting up a Craft project, great info, and listen the discussion about deploy, great info too.
But i´m on the same place, i need to upload my project to Staging, i always to this with craft 2 uploading files ( zip and unzip in server ), change configs and done! I don´t have time right now to learng, git, composer, and a deploy tool. Is there any guideline to do this?
I dont´understand the folder structure in server, everything goes one level up of public_html, and i can rename web folder to public_html and it works?

Comment: yep, you can still do it the way you're used to with Craft 3 -- and yes, you can rename the `web/` directory to whatever you want.

Comment: Great! I will give it a try! Thanks Andrew